# Key to close a fold in vimdiff?

Tags: vim, diff, vimdiff

Pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> on a `+` fold in vim in diff mode causes the fold to open.

What and where do I key if I want to close the fold again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want <kbd>z</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to close the fold. You can read more by typing [`:help fold`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html) in vim. The following is pasted for convenience:

> **zo**        Open one fold under the cursor.  When a count is given, that
>         many folds deep will be opened.  In Visual mode one level of        folds
>   is opened for all lines in the selected area.
>
> **zc**     Close one fold under the cursor.  When a count is given, that
>         many folds deep are closed.  In Visual mode one level of folds      is
>   closed for all lines in the selected area.        'foldenable' will be set.

Also, **za** can be used to toggle the fold open or closed. There is a vim tip on the wiki that describes [mapping the key to the spacebar](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding#) with the following:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Space> @=(foldlevel('.')?'za':"\<Space>")<CR>
```

Comment: It works. Plus now I can have VStudio style folding! If only Vim had a code intelligence, or whatever that thing in VStudio was called. Plus that remap works nicely too. The guy's a genius!

Comment: They called it Intellisense. Vim has some built in shortcuts for this in insert mode: ctrl+n and ctrl+x ctrl+n. See: [:help i_ctrl-N](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-N) & [:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N)